# Do PhD students have to be in a certain age range to receive a scholarship?

Tags: phd, australia, new-zealand

I am going to pursue my Ph.D. in Australia or New Zealand, I don't know if my age can affect my application regarding getting a scholarship. I definitely need a scholarship and stipend to help me to cover my expenses. I am a university lecturer and hold a master's degree in the field of industrial engineering. I am working in the field of mathematical modeling and machine learning.

Comment: How could we know? Most likely, it will not be a problem officially, but it could be a problem depending on the people involved.

Comment: What do the laws of those countries say about age discrimination. They are pretty solid in US, for example. Ideally it shouldn't matter, but the world isn't ideal. And you don't have any options about your age.